# c# razor webpages wrapper for the Database helper with dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-webpages

I've inherited a web site project that has been written in c#/razor WebPages and uses the Database library for data access that returns dynamic objects.

I need to add some audit logging on all the SQL that is executed. I started to write a little wrapper around the database library like below so that  I could add the logging centrally;

```
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> dbExecute(string sql, Array paramslist)
{

    //sql would be eg "SELECT TOP 5 ID FROM TABLENAME WHERE ID > @0"
    //IN THIS CASE THE PARAMSLIST WOULD ONLY HAVE ONE ENTRY

    var db = Database.Open("DatabaseName");
    var queryResult = db.Query(sql, CANT PUT AN ARRAY HERE);
    return queryResult;

}
```

I quickly ran into a problem with parameters as it wont accept an array =(.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can handle the dynamic parameters here..?

Thanks

Comment: Which database library? What types are accepted by Query method? I'd expect it allow an IEnumerable or List of SqlParameter, but not sure what "the Database library" refers to.

Comment: Sorry, it's the webmatrix data class..https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/webmatrix.data.database.query?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2#WebMatrix_Data_Database_Query_System_String_System_Object___. It says it will accept an object for the parameters

Comment: ps @Nikki9696 I have tried passing an Object array as well and it still errors 'No mapping exists from object type System.Object[] to a known managed provider native type'

Answer (score 0):

This was my fault, being stupid...

```
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> dbExecute(string sql, Array paramslist)
```

should have been

```
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> dbExecute(string sql, string[] paramslist)
```

My apologies.